# Mysql C API : How to get one connection per thread

Tags: mysql, c, multithreading, threadpool, mysql-connector

My program is a threaded Mysql C client (compiled with lmysqlclient_r and called mysql_library_init() from main) which consists to search into a Mysql database some domain names.

The domain names (`names` variable) in the array `t_thconf *th` of struct :

```
typedef struct       s_thconf
{
    t_conf  *conf;
    char    *ext;
    char    *origin;
    char    *name;
}                    t_thconf;
```

The struct t_conf contains only mysql configurations like the host_ip, the user, the port... sent to mysql_real_connect().

I process the domain names with this [Thread pool](https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool) in which each call of db_domains_query is a job and is pushed in the job queue like that :

```
  ...
    printf("Making threadpool with %d threads\n", 100);
    threadpool thpool = thpool_init(100);

    while (i < (int)nb_domains)
    {
      printf("%d %s\n", i, th[i].name);
      thpool_add_work(*thpool, (void *)db_domains_query, (void *)&th[i]);
      while ((thpool_jobqueue_length(*thpool) > QUEUE_UNIT))
      usleep(200);
      i += 1;
    }
  ...

// Process one domain name, check if it's existing and update it
void db_domains_query(void *arg)
  {           
    thconf *th = (t_thconf *) arg;
    char query[500];
    char buff[500];
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!con)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "mysql_init() failed\n");
        finish_with_error(con);
      }

    if (mysql_real_connect(con, th->conf->server_ip, th->conf->user, th->conf->password, th->conf->database, (unsigned int)th->conf->port, NULL, 0) == NULL)
      finish_with_error(con);

    mysql_set_character_set(con, "utf8");

    mysql_real_escape_string(con, buff, th->name, strlen(th->name));
    sprintf(query, "SELECT Id, DomainName FROM domains where DomainName LIKE '%s';", buff);
    // printf("Thread #%u working on the query = %s\n" (int)pthread_self(), query);

    if (mysql_query(con, query))
      finish_with_error(con);

    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
    if (result == NULL)
      finish_with_error(con);

    MYSQL_ROW row;
    if ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
      {
        printf("Domain name is found : %s %s \n", row[0], row[1]);
      }
    ...
    mysql_thread_end();
    mysql_free_result(result);
    mysql_close(con);
    return ();
 }
```

This portion of code works well if the number of domain names to be processed is quite reasonable (up to 500,000). However, if I have to deal with a large volume of data (for example > 2,092,900 `names`) **the Mysql server seems to be too much requested.** 
It rejects my client and I receive the error " #1040 - Too many connections", and then " Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip'". 
The `usleep(200)` is only delaying errors.

My guess is :

- On one hand, the mysql max_connections equals 101 (I can't change its value)
- On the other hand, I declare and assign to mysql_init() a new MYSQL *connection into db_domains_query, probably as many times as there are `names`.

So, my question is how can I reused the same connections, considering that 1 connection will equal 1 thread ? And how can I adapt my code to limit  connections ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A common approach is to have m database-threads in a pool (in your case m < 101) and n worker threads, which do the real work. A worker thread then queues a database query, which is processed in order by the workers in the database thread pool, and then dequeues the result afterwards. A database worker takes a query, processes it in its own (exclusive) connection, returns the result into the queue and notifies the corresponding worker thread.

Comment: Ok, I understand the conceptual purpose, thanks. But I don't have an actual idea about how to do it. If you could show some commented example code, it would be great!

Comment: Sorry, but this is way too much effort ;)

Comment: Could you at least describe more this method ? Because it seems to me that your n worker threads are unnecessary in this case. Each name sent to queries is dequeued by parsing the array *th of struct : th[i].name.